# JS export html file code Edit?

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner. I use this code export `<div>` content to html file, but converter file have not `<html></html>`, `<body></body>`, `<head></head>`. please teach me how to add this code to export file? Thx

Html Code:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#downloadLink').click(function(){
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
});
        </script>
```

JS Code:

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {

    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click();
}


var fileName =  'Filename'+'.html';
```

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: I think you have forgot to add `<a id="downloadLink">Click</a>`

Comment: i build input form get text to <div> content, than export this <div> ID location value exprot to html file. But export file only have DIV inside data, now i want use this format add <html><head></head><body></body></html> data to export file. ( I tried edit input JS code, but export file auto remove <html><head><body>code) Y_Y

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/gaotter/xpvt214o/659191/